# SQL difference between =0, ='0', IN(0), IN('0')

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I inherited some code from a coworker and I noticed that the way that some of the code is not consistent
For example, is ther any functional difference between the following:

```
sum(case when (elephants = 0)then 1 else 0 end),

sum(case when (elephants = '0')then 1 else 0 end),

sum(case when (elephants IN (0))then 1 else 0 end),

sum(case when (elephants IN ('0'))then 1 else 0 end);
```

If there isn't a functional difference between using single qutoes or IN vs = when looking for a single value, what other reason could account for it (other than sloppy code)?

Comment: What is the DBMS? Otherwise, these all do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x IN (a, b, c)` means `x = a OR x = b OR x = c`. When the `IN` list contains a single item, `x IN (a)` just means `x = a`.

As for the difference between `0` and `'0'`, the former is an integer, the latter is a character string. The latter can be converted to an integer, so when `elephants` is an integer too, `elephants = 0` and `elephants = '0'` also test the same thing.

There is no real difference between the four.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is for single value but `IN` can have *multiple* values in a set.

example for `=`

```
a = b
```

but for `IN`, instead of writing multiple `OR`

```
a = 1 OR a = 2 or a = 3
```

you can write it as

```
a IN (1,2,3)
```

about single quotes, if the column's data type is numeric, the server automatically parses the string value into numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

In short:

```
= 0 //equal to the number zero
= '0' //equal to the string "0"
IN (0) //appears in the list in parenthesis. In this case, the single-item list of numerical zero
IN ('0') //appears in the list in parenthesis. In this case, the single-item list of string "0"
```